# Gradient color background for visual selections

Tags: visual-block, color, selection

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiOalxCQ1Mw&t=6m12s) from Bisqwit, the selected line is colored by a gradient according to column number. Image is below. He implemented the gradient in a custom terminal emulator. Is there any way to recreate it with a Vim plugin?

[image: Image of source code in Joe editor with a gradient color behind the selected text.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim (and neovim) use some highlighting groups ([`:h highlight-groups`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups)) to define which color a UI component should have.

For the cursor line the group is `hl-CursorLine` ([`:h hl-CursorLine`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-CursorLine)).

Such groups can only contain one color and the code is not made to support the kind of customization you are looking for. So the answer is: it is not possible to recreate that in a vim plugin.

Maybe this could be done by reworking heavily the source code but I don't see such a patch being merged into Vim (maybe into neovim but even there I'm really not sure).